# How to add space between two elements of 60% + 40% width?

Tags: html, css

Hard to explain in the title so i'll elaborate. Obviously I understand that extra space can't be added between two elements that equal to 100% width of the container, but i'm wondering if there's a way to decrease the width of one by 40px.

I'm pretty confident I could do it in JavaScript if needs be but if an easier css solution is available I'd prefer to use that.

To further explain, I'd like a 40px bewteen the two white elements seen in this image: https://gyazo.com/551af056aa516eac2ce3c7b16949a0fa

As you can see I have a large container with a left and right column, with widths of 40% and 60% respectively.

HTML:

```
<div id="homeContentContainer" class="homeContentContainer">

    <div class="leftCol">
        <div class="buyPanel panel">
        </div>
        <div class="sellPanel panel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
        <div class="buyPanel panel">
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- content container -->
```

CSS:

```
.homeContentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.leftCol {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.rightCol {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.buyPanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

.sellPanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering what the reason is for not just making your percentages smaller and work out the pixel calculations manually based on your container size? Only reason I ask this is because calc() is not supported by a lot of browsers so depending on what your target audience is it might not work on some of there browsers. Just curious :)

Comment: @grimesd - calc is supported by all browsers now days. Only old versions of IE still in use lack support.

Comment: @ori drori thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to reduce the `width` by a fixed amount.

> The calc() CSS function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`,
>   `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is required. With calc(), you
>   can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

You can reduce the width of one of them:

```
.homeContentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(60% - 40px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Or split the difference between the 2 elements:

```
.homeContentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(60% - 20px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.leftCol {
    width: calc(40% - 20px);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with a [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Check out this example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 200px;  
  /* This makes .left width 40% and .right 60%*/
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
  grid-gap: 40px; /* 40px gap between .left and .right */
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-gap can be used instead margins ;)